# fatal: Reference has invalid format: 'refs/stash (1)'

Tags: git

I have recently upgraded from `ubuntu 14.04` to `14.10` using `apt-get dist-upgrade`, which seems to have gone smoothly, except that I can no longer use one of my git repositories (on which I had local commits that have not been pushed).

Whenever I run a `git` command, such as `git status` I now received the following message:

> fatal: Reference has invalid format: 'refs/stash (1)'

I tried `git stash clear` thinking that this might be due to a corrupted stash list, but that had no effect (the command ran without errors or outputs, and I am still getting the above error).

Before I `diff` my files manually and create a new repo altogether, is there anything I can try to recover this local repository? I am using `git 2.1.0`

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue was [related to other questions after all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12773488/git-fatal-reference-has-invalid-format-refs-heads-master) even though the error message was different. My home directory is sym-linked to a cloud drive which apparently had some conflicts which it resolved by suffixing some files with `(1)`. Apparently `git` didn't like this, although I'm not sure why it would care about additional files in its directories (I don't know a lot about git internals...)

I ended up just doing a `diff` between my local repo and the remote, nuking the directory, re-copying and applying the `.patch` file.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to solve it by going into `.git/refs/` and removing the *stash (1)* file.